# How to perform a data transfer to an external server

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, gsm, sd-card

So I'm doing a project that involves getting sensor data from several sensors, and then sending them to an external server when a tragic occurs. But I've been having trouble figuring out how to send this data, and I am welcome to advice (I'm still relatively new to Arduino coding).

I'm using an Arduino mega, with a sim900 GSM shield and an SD card. The sensors are just analog reads and a GPS.

I've looked into FTP, a Xively account and http requests to a web server but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Do you have internet service in that GSM shield?

Comment: Yup. The shield has a SIM card with 3G

Comment: You should check for: "Sim900 HTTP POST" on Google. There also should be a lot of libraries for this. You'll have to set up a webserver that accepts HTTP post messages. But you might try using a post dump test server first (https://posttestserver.com/) this worked great for me in the past. But I had an PIC microcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good example of using the **SubmitHttpRequest()** in this article:
[GPRS Shield SIM900 Arduino](https://roysoala.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/gprs-shield-sim900-arduino-get-data-application/)

You could easily modify:
**mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"www.yourwebsite.com/testing.php\"");**

to include a string of the sensor value, and then using a PHP script to MySQL on your webserver. Maybe something like: 
http://**yourwebsite.com**/testing.php?**sensor1**=5&**sensor2**=10